# Thread doesn't terminate upon the condition, Producer-consumer threads

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I would like to implement rather simple task. There are 2 queues (both have limited capacity): `BlockingQueue<String> source` and `BlockingQueue<String> destination`. There are 2 types of threads: `Producer producer` produces a message and stores at the `BlockingQueue<String> source`. The second - `Replacer replacer` picks from the  source, transforms a message and inserts it into the `BlockingQueue<String> destination`.

Two questions/issues:

1. I am not sure that I have correctly implemented the following requirement: transfer messages from the source to destination if the source is not empty and destination is not full.
2. After finishing my program, there is a still running thread called - "Signal Dispatcher". How can I terminate it properly? My program doesn't terminate properly.

Here are the implementations of the relative entities:

Implementation of the source/destination queues.

```
public class BlockingQueueImpl<E> implements BlockingQueue<E> {
private volatile Queue<E> storage = new PriorityQueue<>();
private volatile int capacity;
private volatile int currentNumber;

public BlockingQueueImpl(int capacity) {
    this.capacity = capacity;
    this.storage = new PriorityQueue<E>(capacity);
}

@Override
public synchronized void offer(E element) {
    while (isFull()) {
        try {
            this.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    currentNumber++;
    storage.add(element);
    notifyAll();
}

@Override
public synchronized E poll() {
    while (isEmpty()) {
        try {
            this.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    currentNumber--;
    notifyAll();
    return storage.poll();
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return capacity;
}
public synchronized boolean isFull(){
    return currentNumber > capacity;
}
public synchronized boolean isEmpty(){
    return currentNumber == 0;
}
}
```

Implementation of the producer

```
public class Producer implements Runnable {
    BlockingQueue<String> source;
    String threadName;

    public Producer(BlockingQueue<String> source, String threadName) {
        this.source = source;
        this.threadName = threadName;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!source.isFull()) {
            source.offer(Utilities.generateMessage(threadName));
        }
    }
}
```

Implementation of the consumer

```
public class Replacer implements Runnable {
    BlockingQueue<String> source;
    BlockingQueue<String> destination;
    String threadName;

    public Replacer(BlockingQueue<String> source,
                    BlockingQueue<String> destination,
                    String threadName) {

        this.source = source;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.threadName = threadName;
    }

    public synchronized void replace() {
        destination.offer(Utilities.transformMessage(threadName, source.poll()));
    }
private boolean isRunning() {
        return (!destination.isFull()) && (!source.isEmpty());
    }

@Override
public void run() {
    while (isRunning()) {
        replace();
    }
}


}
```

And helper class

```
    public class Utilities {

        public static final int NUMBER_OF_PRODUCER_THREADS = 3;
        public static final int NUMBER_OF_REPLACER_THREADS = 1000;
        public static final int NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES_TO_READ = 1000;
        public static final int STORAGE_CAPACITY = 100;

        public static String transformMessage(String threadName, String messageToTransform) {
            String[] splittedString = messageToTransform.split(" ");
            String newMessage = "Thread #" + threadName + " transferred message " + splittedString[splittedString.length - 1];
            return newMessage;
        }

        public static String generateMessage(String threadName) {
            return "Thread #" + threadName + " generated message #" + threadName;
        }

        public static void spawnDaemonThreads(String threadName,
                                              int numberOfThreadsToSpawn,
                                              BlockingQueue<String> source,
                                              BlockingQueue<String> destination) {

            if (destination == null) {
                for (int i = 1; i < numberOfThreadsToSpawn + 1; i++) {
                    String name = threadName + i;
                    Producer producer = new Producer(source, name);

                    Thread threadProducer = new Thread(producer);
                    threadProducer.setName(name);
                    threadProducer.setDaemon(true);
                    threadProducer.start();
                }
            } else {
                for (int i = 1; i < numberOfThreadsToSpawn + 1; i++) {
                    String name = threadName + i;
                    Replacer replacer = new Replacer(source, destination, name);

                    Thread threadProducer = new Thread(replacer);
                    threadProducer.setName(name);
                    threadProducer.setDaemon(true);
                    threadProducer.start();
                }
            }


}
}
```

Main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BlockingQueue<String> source = new BlockingQueueImpl<>(Utilities.STORAGE_CAPACITY);
        BlockingQueue<String> destination = new BlockingQueueImpl<>(Utilities.STORAGE_CAPACITY);

        // Create, configure and start PRODUCER threads.
        Utilities.spawnDaemonThreads("Producer", Utilities.NUMBER_OF_PRODUCER_THREADS, source, null);

        // Create, configure and start REPLACER threads.
        Utilities.spawnDaemonThreads("Replacer", Utilities.NUMBER_OF_REPLACER_THREADS, source, destination);

        // Read NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES_TO_READ from destination.
       for (int i = 1; (i < Utilities.NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES_TO_READ) && !destination.isEmpty(); i++) {
        System.out.println(destination.poll());
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be "if the destination is not full and the source is not empty"?

Comment: Yeah, indeed, you are right. Fixed my question.

Comment: You've used a single `&` in the `while` loop's condition `((!destination.isFull())& !(source.isEmpty()))`, it should be `((!destination.isFull()) && !(source.isEmpty()))`

Comment: Also, your program will never exit if the number of objects added to the `destination` is not greater then the value of `NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES_TO_READ`, that is because of the `for` loop in the main thread (the `poll()` method will block).

Comment: @Titus, thank you. Your comments helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working code.

```
     /**
     * Class {@code BlockingQueueImpl} is the implementation of the Blocking Queue.
     * This class provides thread-safe operations
     * {@code public void offer(E element)} and {@code public E poll()}
     */

public class BlockingQueueImpl<E> implements BlockingQueue<E> {
    private volatile Queue<E> storage = new PriorityQueue<>();
    private volatile int capacity;
    private volatile int currentNumber;

    public BlockingQueueImpl(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.storage = new PriorityQueue<E>(capacity);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void offer(E element) {
        while (isFull()) {
            try {
                this.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        storage.add(element);
        currentNumber++;
        notifyAll();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized E poll() {
        E polledElement;
        while (isEmpty()) {
            try {
                this.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        notifyAll();
        polledElement = storage.poll();
        currentNumber--;
        return polledElement;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return capacity;
    }
    public synchronized boolean isFull(){
        return currentNumber >= capacity;
    }
    public synchronized boolean isEmpty(){
        return currentNumber == 0;
    }
}

public class Producer implements Runnable {
    BlockingQueue<String> source;
    String threadName;

    public Producer(BlockingQueue<String> source, String threadName) {
        this.source = source;
        this.threadName = threadName;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!source.isFull()) {
            source.offer(Utilities.generateMessage(threadName));
        }
    }
}

public class Replacer implements Runnable {
    BlockingQueue<String> source;
    BlockingQueue<String> destination;
    String threadName;

    public Replacer(BlockingQueue<String> source,
                    BlockingQueue<String> destination,
                    String threadName) {

        this.source = source;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.threadName = threadName;
    }

    public synchronized void replace() {
        destination.offer(Utilities.transformMessage(threadName, source.poll()));
    }

    //Continue execution of a thread if a destination is not full and source is not empty.
    private boolean isRunning() {
        return (!destination.isFull()) && (!source.isEmpty());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (isRunning()) {
            replace();
        }
    }
}
public class Utilities {

    public static final int NUMBER_OF_PRODUCER_THREADS = 3;
    public static final int NUMBER_OF_REPLACER_THREADS = 1000;
    public static final int NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES_TO_READ = 1000;
    public static final int STORAGE_CAPACITY = 100;

    public static String transformMessage(String threadName, String messageToTransform) {
        String[] splittedString = messageToTransform.split(" ");
        String newMessage = "Thread #" + threadName + " transferred message " + splittedString[splittedString.length - 1];
        return newMessage;
    }

    public static String generateMessage(String threadName) {
        return "Thread #" + threadName + " generated message #" + threadName;
    }

    public static void spawnDaemonThreads(String threadName,
                                          int numberOfThreadsToSpawn,
                                          BlockingQueue<String> source,
                                          BlockingQueue<String> destination) {

        if (destination == null) {
            for (int i = 1; i < numberOfThreadsToSpawn + 1; i++) {
                String name = threadName + i;
                Producer producer = new Producer(source, name);

                Thread threadProducer = new Thread(producer);
                threadProducer.setName(name);
                threadProducer.setDaemon(true);
                threadProducer.start();
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 1; i < numberOfThreadsToSpawn + 1; i++) {
                String name = threadName + i;
                Replacer replacer = new Replacer(source, destination, name);

                Thread threadProducer = new Thread(replacer);
                threadProducer.setName(name);
                threadProducer.setDaemon(true);
                threadProducer.start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```